# How to interpret the output and create the rules

Tags: usb, usb-modem

When booting 14.04 with the USB Modem in place the following messages appear:

```
[28.956433] system-udevd[384]:NAME="ttyUSB_utps_diag" ignored, kernel device nodes can be renamed; please fix it in /etc/udev/rules.d/10-Huawei-Data.rules:425
[28.978546] system-udevd[384]:NAME="ttyUSB_utps_diag" ignored, kernel device nodes can be renamed; please fix it in /etc/udev/rules.d/10-Huawei-Data.rules:426
[28.997782] system-udevd[384]:NAME="ttyUSB_utps_diag" ignored, kernel device nodes can be renamed; please fix it in /etc/udev/rules.d/10-Huawei-Data.rules:424
```

Looking at the file mentioned 10-Huawei-Data.rules, and using the .425, .426 and .424 as line numbers, it can be seen they look as if the numbers refer to other than the assumed numbers:

Line numbers if that is what is meant by the above, in 10-Huawei-Data.rule

```
424     SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{modalias}=="usb:v12D1p1436*", KERNEL=="ttyUSB*", ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00",
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="ff", NAME="ttyUSB_utps_modem"

425     SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{modalias}=="usb:v12D1p1436*", KERNEL=="ttyUSB*", ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="03",
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="ff", NAME="ttyUSB_utps_diag"

426     SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{modalias}=="usb:v12D1p1436*", KERNEL=="ttyUSB*", ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="04",
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="ff", NAME="ttyUSB_utps_pcui"
```

Had the problem after the previous update to 14.04 and fixed it by reinstalling the driver, the last upgrade again effectively removed the modem from use and I haven't been able to fix the problem this time.

lsusb says the modem, Huawei E173, is still there.

How could I fix this this time?